# search json file using intent

Tags: android, json, android-intent

What is the correct MIME type for json file(json extnesion) so that only see json files show up when I am browsing the file system through intent?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("application/json");
    Intent i = Intent.createChooser(intent, "View Default File Manager");
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

thanks

Answer (score 7):

Surprisingly, Android does NOT support "json" (and "js" for javascript extension) as a MIME type. This is clear, for example, from the source codes of [MimeUtils](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-5.0.2_r1/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java). Also you can use [`MimeTypeMap`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html) helper class and find out that:

```
MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("json");
```

returns `null`;

The only most close MIME type that can be used instead of "application/json" is "application/octet-stream": it matches "*.json" files among other things, but a lot of other stuff as well. At least it filters out images, texts, music files and videos.